# find density function from distribution function

Tags: integration, density-function

I have this distribution function

f(x) =
\begin{cases}
1-{x^\frac{-1}3)},  & \text{if $x$ >=1 } \\
0, & \text{if $x$  < 1}
\end{cases}

to find the density function I know that I need to do an integral, but in some reason I dont get the correct answer,

this is the correct answer

f(x) =
\begin{cases}
\frac{1}3x^\frac{-4}3,  & \text{if $x$ >=1 } \\
0, & \text{if $x$  < 1}
\end{cases}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the cumulative distribution function is $F$, then the probability density function is $F'$. You seem to have the terms backwards.

---

The first function $F$ given by

$$F(x)=\begin{cases}
1-x^{-1/3}  & \text{if $x \geq 1$ } \\
0 & \text{if $x< 1$}
\end{cases}$$

is the distribution function. (You can see this because $F$ is nondecreasing and continuous and $\lim_{x\to-\infty}F(x)=0$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}F(x)=1$).

The second function $f$ given by
$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
\frac{1}{3}x^{-4/3}  & \text{if $x\geq 1$ } \\
0 & \text{if $x< 1$}
\end{cases}$$

is the density function.

---

Given the cumulative distribution function $F$, find the density function $f$ by differentiation:

$$f(x)=F'(x)$$

for all $x<1$ and all $x>1$.

---

If instead you were given the density function $f$, you can find the cumulative distribution function $F$ using integration:

$$F(x)=\int_1^x f(t)dt$$

for all $x\geq 1$.